# XCode: Seamlessly persist location updates

Tags: swift, xcode, core-location, viewcontroller

I'm making an ios app that involves tracking the user's location. I want the location to be tracked regardless of what viewcontroller the user is in. Is there a way to get this constant location tracking effect without having to turn location updates off/on everytime the user moves to a new viewcontroller? Do I need some kind of singleton?

Comment: @boraseoksoon Stop adding "thanks in advance" to every single question - there should never be thanks added to questions, and you've now done it to many questions.

Answer (score 0):

Implement locationManager delegate in other object class, not in ViewController. Then, inside this object, create var containing location, and use this var in all view controllers. You can use this object as singleton or pass it between controllers.

Answer (score 0):

There are several practices for using the location manager and its delegates. Some say the best way is to implement the location manager in the application delegate, others use it in a view controller while it is controlling the model object location.

I prefer, like Damian Dudycz proposes, to uses a separate model class for the location. This doesn't need to be a singleton. For instance you define a class that provides you all the location specific information that you need for your app. This class has the necessary properties and methods needed for the location specific needs you have in your app. Next to that you enable location updates in background in your project capabilities.

You then could end up with a class like:

```
class myLocationClass: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    //Properties
    var myLocations = [CLLocations]()
    var myGeocodeName = ""
    var myDistanceCovered = 0.0
    var myLocationManager : CLLocationManager? //You can also make this lazy to prevent optional properties
    var ... etc.
```

You can then put same CLLocation specific methods in this class, for instance:

```
func getLocationName(from location: CLLocation) {
//Your reverse geocoding code here.
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,         didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
//Your location update stuff here.
}
```

From your various view controllers you can now call all the public properties and methods to start updating locations, get values and stop updating locations. I've done it this way and it saves me a lot of headaches maintaining the code, since all my location code is within a single class.

The draw back is that your class might get quite big and again difficult to maintain. For me, this has not happened yet.

Hope this helps.